# How to force adjust application window size in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, java

there is a particular program that I want to force adjusting its size, namely, *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 5*.

Its main window size is adjustable. However, the sub-programs such as writing assistant are forced to an inconveniently small window size. Whenever you maximize the window by the conventional approach (the button at the top-right), it shrinks to the original size.

I had tried some alternatives such as a tiny neat program AltMove but didn't work. My guess is LDOCE5 is written in Java so that AltMove cannot override it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps give [ResizeEnable](http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/ResizeEnable/) a try.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. The program automatically redraws the window after resizing.

Answer (score 0):

I seems some fixed size windows cannot be resized by any utility, you would have to hack the exe binary by using a resource editor or PE editor tool, but is complex for most to do and no guarantee it can be done.

Give this one a try

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11799/turn-non-resizeable-windows-into-rezieable-windows/

Edit: appears it does not work for W7, sorry.